# Draw curved lines with arrow in LaTeX (TikZ)

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows

I need to write a paper and include some graphics. The [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/76lXF.png)  I want to include by TikZ is the one on the link. The idee is to draw three curved lines, en put in the middle an arrow (the directions in this example are just random) en at both ends of the line an arrow.

I have no idea how to do this, the TikZ manual isn't very helpful. I hope that someone can help me!

Comment: If the Tikz manual is too much then you should start with something more basic: [A Minimal Introduction to Tikz](http://cremeronline.com/LaTeX/minimaltikz.pdf)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe with the `decorations.marking` library:

```
\documentclass[margin=.1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[arrowmark/.style 2 args={decoration={markings,mark=at position #1 with \arrow{#2}}}]
\draw[postaction={decorate},
    arrowmark={.5}{<},
    arrowmark={.9}{>},
    arrowmark={.15}{<}
    ](0,0)to[bend right=45](2,0);
\draw[
    postaction={decorate},
    arrowmark={.5}{<},
    arrowmark={.9}{<},
    arrowmark={.15}{<}
    ](.5,-.75)to[bend left=45](1.5,1);
\draw[
    postaction={decorate},
    arrowmark={.5}{<},
    arrowmark={.9}{<},
    arrowmark={.15}{>}
    ](1.5,-.75)to[bend right=45](.5,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: let me know if you need to place the letters too...

Comment: Thank you very much! I can place the letters by using the command: \node[font =\footnotesize] at (0.25,-0.5) {z};