# Oriented curves

Tags: pgfplots, arrows, books

Can someone link me to a tutorial or some examples of how to make oriented curves using `pgfplots`?  Something along the lines of

[image]

I'm not asking for someone to spend the time reproducing the above for me, I'd just like a link to a tutorial/ example of something similar.  Google just isn't coming up with anything when I type "pgfplots oriented curves".  Thanks.

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/199814/draw-curved-lines-with-arrow-in-latex-tikz

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While @HansPeterE.Kristiansen has provided a useful link showing how to place individual arrows along the path, you can automate this a bit too as in:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\tikzset{
  arrows along my path/.style={
    postaction={
      decorate,
      decoration={
        markings,
        mark=between positions 0.03 and 1 step 24pt with {\arrow{Stealth[length=5pt]}},
   }}}}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
  \coordinate (C) at (1.5in,0);
  \coordinate (B) at (3in,0);

  \draw [arrows along my path]
        (A) .. controls ++(3,2) and ++(-3,-2) .. 
        (C)
            .. controls ++(-3,2) and ++(-3,-5) ..
        (B);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]